# Text editor using angular4 component

Tags: angular

Simple text editor that allows user to choose the style of font, size, color. I tried implementing the CKEditor, but i have some customisation issue.
So, am looking for a simple angular4 text editor.
[image: this is the required design]

Comment: This is not the appropriate way of asking a question on this forum. Show us what have we tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I use "[ngx-quill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-quill)" as a WYSIWYG Editor in my Angular4 project.

This is an Angular (>=2) component for rich text editor Quill

```
angular v4 - ngx-quill <=1.6.0
angular v5 - ngx-quill > 1.6.0
angular v6 - ngx-quill >= 3.0.0
```

- [demo-page](https://killercodemonkey.github.io/ngx-quill-example/)